# cucumber-js Unexpected Token ILLEGAL

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, cucumber, zombie.js

I am trying to set up cucumber-js grunt and zombie.  I was fallowing a tutorial and it seems that when I try to run cucumber-js I get this:

```
C:\webroot\Sari>cucumber-js
C:\webroot\Sari\node_modules\zombie\node_modules\jsdom\node_modules\cssstyle\lib\CSSStyleDeclaration.js:26
/**
^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
  at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:73:16)
  at Module._compile (module.js:443:25)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
  at Module.load (C:\Users\Sari.Rahal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cucumber\node_modules\coffee-script\lib\coffee-script\register.js:45:36)
  at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
  at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
  at require (module.js:384:17)
  at Object.<anonymous> (C:\webroot\Sari\node_modules\zombie\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\level2\style.js:7:16)
  at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
  at Module.load (C:\Users\Sari.Rahal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cucumber\node_modules\coffee-script\lib\coffee-script\register.js:45:36)
  at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
  at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
  at require (module.js:384:17)
  at Object.<anonymous> (C:\webroot\Sari\node_modules\zombie\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\index.js:9:1)
  at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
  at Module.load (C:\Users\Sari.Rahal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cucumber\node_modules\coffee-script\lib\coffee-script\register.js:45:36)
  at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
  at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
  at require (module.js:384:17)
  at Object.<anonymous> (C:\webroot\Sari\node_modules\zombie\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom.js:9:11)
  at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
  at Module.load (C:\Users\Sari.Rahal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cucumber\node_modules\coffee-script\lib\coffee-script\register.js:45:36)
  at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
  at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
  at require (module.js:384:17)
  at Object.<anonymous> (C:\webroot\Sari\node_modules\zombie\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\browser\index.js:2:21)
  at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
  at Module.load (C:\Users\Sari.Rahal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cucumber\node_modules\coffee-script\lib\coffee-script\register.js:45:36)
  at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
  at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
  at require (module.js:384:17)
  at Object.<anonymous> (C:\webroot\Sari\node_modules\zombie\lib\document.js:13:16)
  at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
  at Module.load (C:\Users\Sari.Rahal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cucumber\node_modules\coffee-script\lib\coffee-script\register.js:45:36)
  at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
  at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
  at require (module.js:384:17)
  at Object.<anonymous> (C:\webroot\Sari\node_modules\zombie\lib\history.js:42:20)
  at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
  at Module.load (C:\Users\Sari.Rahal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cucumber\node_modules\coffee-script\lib\coffee-script\register.js:45:36)
  at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
  at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
  at require (module.js:384:17)
  at Object.<anonymous> (C:\webroot\Sari\node_modules\zombie\lib\tabs.js:7:21)
  at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
  at Module.load (C:\Users\Sari.Rahal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cucumber\node_modules\coffee-script\lib\coffee-script\register.js:45:36)
  at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
  at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
  at require (module.js:384:17)
  at Object.<anonymous> (C:\webroot\Sari\node_modules\zombie\lib\index.js:18:12)
  at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
  at Module.load (C:\Users\Sari.Rahal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cucumber\node_modules\coffee-script\lib\coffee-script\register.js:45:36)
  at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
  at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
  at require (module.js:384:17)
  at Object.<anonymous> (C:\webroot\Sari\features\support\world.js:3:14)
  at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
  at Module.load (C:\Users\Sari.Rahal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cucumber\node_modules\coffee-script\lib\coffee-script\register.js:45:36)
  at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
  at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
  at require (module.js:384:17)
  at C:\Users\Sari.Rahal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cucumber\lib\cucumber\cli\support_code_loader.js:60:29
  at Array.forEach (native)
  at Object.wrapper (C:\Users\Sari.Rahal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cucumber\lib\cucumber\cli\support_code_loader.js:59:15)
  at Object.initializer (C:\Users\Sari.Rahal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cucumber\lib\cucumber\cli\support_code_loader.js:20:37)
  at Object.Library (C:\Users\Sari.Rahal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cucumber\lib\cucumber\support_code\library.js:131:25)
  at Object.getSupportCodeLibrary (C:\Users\Sari.Rahal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cucumber\lib\cucumber\cli\support_code_loader.js:10:58)
  at Object.getSupportCodeLibrary (C:\Users\Sari.Rahal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cucumber\lib\cucumber\cli\configuration.js:51:52)
  at Object.getSupportCodeLibrary (C:\Users\Sari.Rahal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cucumber\lib\cucumber\runtime.js:42:46)
  at Object.start (C:\Users\Sari.Rahal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cucumber\lib\cucumber\runtime.js:17:37)
  at Object.runSuiteWithConfiguration (C:\Users\Sari.Rahal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cucumber\lib\cucumber\cli.js:19:15)
  at Object.run (C:\Users\Sari.Rahal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cucumber\lib\cucumber\cli.js:12:14)
  at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Sari.Rahal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cucumber\bin\cucumber.js:4:5)
  at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
  at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
  at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
  at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
  at startup (node.js:129:16)
  at node.js:814:3
```

From what I read it could be a JavaScript interpreter having issues.  I am not sure where to start with this one.  Do I have the wrong modules set up?  Do I need to update something?  if not: What file do I need to look into?  Any insight would be helpful at this point.  If you need any more details, please let me know.

## More Info

## features/myFeature.feature

```
Feature: Example feature
  As a user of Google
  I want to have documentation on Google on an About page
  So that I can learn about Google

  Scenario: Reading About Google
    Given I am on the Google homepage
    When I go to the About page
    Then I should see "About Google" as the page title
    And I should see the text "Google's mission is to organize the world's information and make it universally accessible and useful."
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Issue was I was running the newest version of zombie that changed the format of the code.  After rolling back to the previous version, it worked.